# C# File.AppendText to next line

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have this Method

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"\IPSM\DeviceConfig.EXM");    
int NumOFLines = 6;    
String[] ListLines = new string[NumOFLines];    
for (int i = 1; i < NumOFLines; i++)
{    
    ListLines[i] = tr.ReadLine();    
}    
using (StreamWriter output = File.AppendText(@"\temp\exm.txt"))    
{    
    output.Write(ListLines[5]);    
}    
tr.Close();    
return;
```

That reads line 5 of a text file them appends to another text file, the output is

```
Line1    
Line2LINE5 //from the other text file
```

I want

```
Line1    
Line2    
LINE5 //from the other text file
```

How do I get it to output to the next line I am limited to the Compact Framework

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7ack4zyt) to write a line with the CrLf.

```
        using (StreamWriter output = File.AppendText(@"\temp\exm.txt"))     
        {     
            output.WriteLine(ListLines[5]);     
        }
```

So your file always ends with a new line (delete or edit your exising file to ensure it).
If you can't, try the following :

```
        using (StreamWriter output = File.AppendText(@"\temp\exm.txt"))     
        {     
            output.WriteLine();
            output.Write(ListLines[5]); 
        }
```

WriteLine should be available on CF, if not your can append the newline to the string argument of Write

```
            output.Write(ListLines[5] + Environment.NewLine);
```

or

```
            output.Write(ListLines[5] + "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example in this link it shows the use of 'Environment.NewLine' i'm not sure if you can use this on the compact framework but its worth a shot. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx